# Indian, USA resident, visit Europe , London Transit , transit visa needed?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, transit-visas

Confusion is because I hold a USA visa but not traveling TO the USA. I'm visiting Europe for tourism.

I am an Indian Passport holder, working in the USA (NOTE: Holding USA F1, Student Visa).
I am visiting Sweden for New Year and have received a visiting visa (NOTE: Holding Schengen visiting visa ).
I have booked British Airways flight transiting through London (NOTE: Same Terminal for arriving and departing flights at London, two hours apart).
I have a return ticket confirmed from USA to Sweden to back to USA .

Would I need a Transit visa in this case?

UK GOV says:

> You’ll need a visa to pass through the UK in transit (unless you’re
>   exempt) You should apply for a Direct Airside Transit visa if you
>   arrive in the UK on a flight and leave again without passing through
>   immigration control.
>
> Exemptions You don’t need a visa if you have one of the following:
>
> a visa for Canada, New Zealand, Australia or the USA (this can be used
>   for travel to any country) a residence permit issued by Australia or
>   New Zealand you have a common format residence permit issued by an
>   European Economic Area (EEA) country or Switzerland a resident permit
>   issued by Canada after 28 June 2002 a uniform format category D visa
>   for entry into a country in the European Economic Area (EEA) or
>   Switzerland an Irish biometric visa a Schengen Approved Destination
>   Scheme (ADS) group tourism visa where th e holder is travelling to to
>   the Schengen country that issued the visa a flight ticket from the
>   Schengen area, if you can prove that you entered the Schengen area in
>   the previous 30 days on the basis of a valid Schengen ADS visa a valid
>   USA I-551 Temporary Immigrant visa issued by the USA (a wet-ink stamp
>   version will not be accepted) a valid USA permanent residence card
>   issued by the USA on or after 21 April 1998 an expired USA I-551
>   Permanent Residence card issued by the USA on or after 21 April 1998,
>   with a valid I-797 letter authorising extension a valid standalone US
>   Immigration Form 155A/155B issued by the USA (attached to a sealed
>   brown envelope) All visas and residence permits must be valid.

Does point 1 apply as an exemption in my case?

Comment: What does it say? Did you read it? Why do you doubt official government information?

Comment: It says " visa for USA " but does not specifically mention if the point is valid even if you're traveling from USA to another country . Because logically it makes sense if it is used for my travel TO the USA .

Comment: Yes, it _does_ say! "this can be used for travel to any country"

Comment: Ok Thanks Mike ! I was afraid I would need one because I misinterpreted. I'm just hoping the airlines check-in counter is informed enough to let me through , and not detain me for not having a DATV. I might have to print out the page on UK gov website too , just to be safe

Comment: Also just a little curious why UK considers the USA visa as a clause for exemption of a DATV . I mean , why would UK use the possession of US VISA even though I'm not traveling to the USA ?

Comment: Because, if you have a US visa, you are not likely to try to illegally immigrate in the UK.

Comment: Hello, just wanted to update that Michael was spot on . Border Patrol agreed US visa is good enough for London transit .